# Inner product spaces and isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, isometry, adjoint-operators

In an inner product space $V$ and $T \in Hom(V,V)$ the following conditions are equivalent:-

b) $T^*T=I$ where $T^*$ is adjoint of $T$ and $I$ is identity operator

c) $T$ is an isometry
How to prove this

Comment: I have to proved the two parts of this proof. I wanna know how to prove that b is equivalent to c

Comment: What is condition (a)?

Comment: Also, I think part b) should be $T^* T = I$, not $TT^* = I$, or $V$ should be assumed to be finite-dimensional. In infinite dimensional spaces, there are examples of linear operators $T$ which are not isometries, but for which $TT^* = I$, such as the left-shift operator on $\ell^2$.

Comment: Now please help in solving this

Answer (score 1):

From b) to c) is easier. If $T^* T = I$, then
$$\|Tx\|^2 = \langle Tx, Tx \rangle = \langle T^* Tx, x \rangle = \langle x, x\rangle = \|x\|^2,$$
proving $T$ is an isometry.

On the other hand, if $T$ is an isometry, then using the [polarisation identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), we see that $T$ also preserves inner products, i.e. $\langle Tx, Ty\rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ for all $x, y$. If we fix $x$, then we get
$$\langle x, y \rangle = \langle Tx, Ty \rangle = \langle T^* Tx, y\rangle \implies \langle T^*T x - x, y\rangle = 0$$
for all $y$. That is, $T^* T x - x$ is a vector orthogonal to every vector. The only such vector is $0$ (consider $y = T^* T x - x$), hence
$$T^* T x - x = 0 \implies T^* T x = x,$$
i.e. $T^* T = I$.